# why beans are rejecting and what does no URL paths identified means?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am using spring:3.0:
I am updating the question with some changes in following xml files.

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
           <servlet-class>
           org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
      </servlet-mapping>
```

I have the updated spring-servlet.xml:

```
    <bean id="localeChangeInterceptor"
            class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
            <property name="paramName" value="lang" />
        </bean>

        <bean id="localeResolver"
            class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.CookieLocaleResolver">
            <property name="defaultLocale" value="en" />
        </bean>

        <bean id="handlerMapping"
            class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping">
            <property name="interceptors">
                <ref bean="localeChangeInterceptor" />
            </property>
                </bean>
        <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter"/>
        <mvc:resources mapping="/images/**"  location="/images/"/>
        <mvc:resources location="/css/**" mapping="/css/"/>
        <mvc:resources location="/css/**" mapping="/css/"/>
        <mvc:default-servlet-handler/>
        <mvc:annotation-driven />
      <context:component-scan base-package="com.dz.hrportal.controller" />
    <bean       class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
            <property name="prefix" value="/jsp/" />
            <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
        </bean>
        <bean id="messageSource"
            class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
            <property name="basename" value="classpath:messages" />
            <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
        </bean>
```

now It is seems my web application is running the problem here I can see on the server log which says:

```
10:48:46,058 DEBUG BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping:86 - Rejected bean name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.config.viewControllerHandlerAdapter': no URL paths identified
10:48:46,058 DEBUG BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping:86 - Rejected bean name 'abstractController': no URL paths identified
10:48:46,059 DEBUG BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping:86 - Rejected bean name 'adminLoginController': no URL paths identified
10:48:46,059 DEBUG BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping:86 - Rejected bean name 'empLeaveApplyController': no URL paths identified
10:48:46,059 DEBUG BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping:86 - Rejected bean name 'empRegisterController': no URL paths identified
10:48:46,059 DEBUG BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping:86 - Rejected bean name 'fileDownloadController': no URL paths identified
10:48:46,059 DEBUG BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping:86 - Rejected bean name 'fileUploadController': no URL paths identified
10:48:46,060 DEBUG BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping:86 - Rejected bean name 'globalHomeController': no URL paths identified
10:48:46,060 DEBUG BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping:86 - Rejected bean name 'leaveStatusController': no URL paths identified
10:48:46,060 DEBUG BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping:86 - Rejected bean name 'raiseQueryController': no URL paths identified
10:48:46,060 DEBUG BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping:86 - Rejected bean name 'upComingLeavesController': no URL paths identified
10:48:46,060 DEBUG BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping:86 - Rejected bean name 'viewProfileController': no URL paths identified
10:48:46,060 DEBUG BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping:86 - Rejected bean name 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor': no URL paths identified
10:48:46,060 DEBUG BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping:86 - Rejected bean name 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor': no URL paths identified
10:48:46,061 DEBUG BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping:86 - Rejected bean name 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor': no URL paths identified
10:48:46,061 DEBUG BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping:86 - Rejected bean name 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor': no URL paths identified
10:48:46,061 DEBUG BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping:86 - Rejected bean name 'multipartResolver': no URL paths identified
10:48:46,061 DEBUG BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping:86 - Rejected bean name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver#0': no URL paths identified
10:48:46,061 DEBUG BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping:86 - Rejected bean name 'messageSource': no URL paths identified
10:48:46,061 DEBUG BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping:86 - Rejected bean name 'localeChangeInterceptor': no URL paths identified
10:48:46,061 DEBUG BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping:86 - Rejected bean name 'localeResolver': no URL paths identified
10:48:46,062 DEBUG BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping:86 - Rejected bean name 'handlerMapping': no URL paths identified
10:48:46,062 DEBUG BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping:86 - Rejected bean name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter#0': no URL paths identified
10:48:46,062 DEBUG BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping:86 - Rejected bean name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler#0': no URL paths identified
10:48:46,062 DEBUG BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping:86 - Rejected bean name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping#0': no URL paths identified
10:48:46,062 DEBUG BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping:86 - Rejected bean name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler#1': no URL paths identified
10:48:46,062 DEBUG BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping:86 - Rejected bean name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping#1': no URL paths identified
10:48:46,063 DEBUG BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping:86 - Rejected bean name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler#2': no URL paths identified
10:48:46,063 DEBUG BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping:86 - Rejected bean name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping#2': no URL paths identified
10:48:46,063 DEBUG BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping:86 - Rejected bean name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.DefaultServletHttpRequestHandler#0': no URL paths identified
10:48:46,063 DEBUG BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping:86 - Rejected bean name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping#3': no URL paths identified
10:48:46,063 DEBUG BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping:86 - Rejected bean name 'mailSender': no URL paths identified
10:48:46,063 DEBUG BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping:86 - Rejected bean name 'org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor$ImportAwareBeanPostProcessor#0': no URL paths identified
10:48:46,063 DEBUG BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping:86 - Rejected bean name 'environment': no URL paths identified
10:48:46,064 DEBUG BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping:86 - Rejected bean name 'systemProperties': no URL paths identified
10:48:46,064 DEBUG BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping:86 - Rejected bean name 'systemEnvironment': no URL paths identified
10:48:46,064 DEBUG BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping:86 - Rejected bean name 'servletContext': no URL paths identified
10:48:46,064 DEBUG BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping:86 - Rejected bean name 'servletConfig': no URL paths identified
10:48:46,064 DEBUG BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping:86 - Rejected bean name 'contextParameters': no URL paths identified
10:48:46,065 DEBUG BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping:86 - Rejected bean name 'contextAttributes': no URL paths identified
10:48:46,065 DEBUG BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping:86 - Rejected bean name 'importRegistry': no URL paths identified
10:48:46,066 DEBUG BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping:86 - Rejected bean name 'applicationEventMulticaster': no URL paths identified
0:48:46,197 DEBUG DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping:86 - Rejected bean name 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor': no URL paths identified
10:48:46,197 DEBUG DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping:86 - Rejected bean name 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor': no URL paths identified
10:48:46,197 DEBUG DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping:86 - Rejected bean name 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor': no URL paths identified
10:48:46,198 DEBUG DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping:86 - Rejected bean name 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor': no URL paths identified
10:48:46,198 DEBUG DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping:86 - Rejected bean name 'multipartResolver': no URL paths identified
10:48:46,198 DEBUG DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping:86 - Rejected bean name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver#0': no URL paths identified
10:48:46,198 DEBUG DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping:86 - Rejected bean name 'messageSource': no URL paths identified
10:48:46,199 DEBUG DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping:86 - Rejected bean name 'localeChangeInterceptor': no URL paths identified
10:48:46,199 DEBUG DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping:86 - Rejected bean name 'localeResolver': no URL paths identified
10:48:46,199 DEBUG DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping:86 - Rejected bean name 'handlerMapping': no URL paths identified
10:48:46,199 DEBUG DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping:86 - Rejected bean name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter#0': no URL paths identified
10:48:46,199 DEBUG DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping:86 - Rejected bean name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler#0': no URL paths identified
10:48:46,199 DEBUG DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping:86 - Rejected bean name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping#0': no URL paths identified
10:48:46,200 DEBUG DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping:86 - Rejected bean name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler#1': no URL paths identified
10:48:46,200 DEBUG DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping:86 - Rejected bean name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping#1': no URL paths identified
10:48:46,200 DEBUG DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping:86 - Rejected bean name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler#2': no URL paths identified
10:48:46,200 DEBUG DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping:86 - Rejected bean name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping#2': no URL paths identified
10:48:46,200 DEBUG DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping:86 - Rejected bean name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.DefaultServletHttpRequestHandler#0': no URL paths identified
10:48:46,200 DEBUG DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping:86 - Rejected bean name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping#3': no URL paths identified
10:48:46,201 DEBUG DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping:86 - Rejected bean name 'mailSender': no URL paths identified
10:48:46,201 DEBUG DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping:86 - Rejected bean name 'org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor$ImportAwareBeanPostProcessor#0': no URL paths identified
10:48:46,201 DEBUG DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping:86 - Rejected bean name 'environment': no URL paths identified
10:48:46,201 DEBUG DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping:86 - Rejected bean name 'systemProperties': no URL paths identified
10:48:46,201 DEBUG DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping:86 - Rejected bean name 'systemEnvironment': no URL paths identified
10:48:46,201 DEBUG DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping:86 - Rejected bean name 'servletContext': no URL paths identified
10:48:46,202 DEBUG DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping:86 - Rejected bean name 'servletConfig': no URL paths identified
10:48:46,202 DEBUG DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping:86 - Rejected bean name 'contextParameters': no URL paths identified
10:48:46,202 DEBUG DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping:86 - Rejected bean name 'contextAttributes': no URL paths identified
10:48:46,202 DEBUG DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping:86 - Rejected bean name 'importRegistry': no URL paths identified
10:48:46,202 DEBUG DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping:86 - Rejected bean name 'applicationEventMulticaster': no URL paths identified
0:48:46,313 DEBUG DispatcherServlet:617 - Unable to locate RequestToViewNameTranslator with name 'viewNameTranslator': using default [org.springframework.web.servlet.view.DefaultRequestToViewNameTranslator@196e136]
10:48:46,313 DEBUG DefaultListableBeanFactory:246 - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver#0'
10:48:46,314 DEBUG DispatcherServlet:506 - Published WebApplicationContext of servlet 'spring' as ServletContext attribute with name [org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.CONTEXT.spring]
10:48:46,314  INFO DispatcherServlet:446 - FrameworkServlet 'spring': initialization completed in 1126 ms
10:48:46,314 DEBUG DispatcherServlet:136 - Servlet 'spring' configured successfully
```

why the beans are rejecting,does any one know the way to fix it.

Comment: have you tried adding a AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter bean def like my answer suggested?

Answer (score 2):

In the spring [docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch16s11.html) it says

> if you are defining custom HandlerMappings or HandlerAdapters, then
>   you need to make sure that a corresponding custom
>   DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping and/or AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter
>   is defined as well - provided that you intend to use @RequestMapping.

Since you are defining DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping you will need to define the adapter as well:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter"/>
```

Comment: Hey thank you man for the suggestion to add AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter abd I have gone through   http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch16s11.html and solved the issue.

Comment: org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter now is DEPRECATED